# Type of constrained string values

Tags: types, f#, refinement-type

Just beginning my journey into F#, is it possible to define a type that is constrained to a specific set of string values? F.ex. it can only represent the values `"Foo"`, `"Bar"` and `"Baz"`, trying to assign any other value to it will throw an error or even better fail at compile time.

UPDATE:
So far, I thought about creating a type that is a string and using a create function:

```
type Constrained = string
let createConstrained (constrained : Constrained) = 
    match constrained with
        | "foo" -> constrained
        | "bar" -> constrained
        | "baz" -> constrained
        | _ -> failwith "Can be only foo, bar or baz"
```

Next, I thought about using a DU and some kind of function that returns the string based on the option (is that the right name for it?):

```
type Constrained = FOO | BAR | BAZ
let constrainedString constrained =
    match constrained with
        | FOO -> "foo"
        | BAR -> "bar"
        | BAZ -> "baz"
        | _ -> failwith "Can only be foo, bar or baz"
```

Not quite sure if either one is the way to go.

Comment: You should show what you have tried so that we can see what you are thinking and help to explain why you should not be thinking that.

Comment: Of interest: [F# type definition with expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089875/f-type-definition-with-expression)

Comment: Updated as requested

Comment: Of interest: [Constraints (F#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233203.aspx)

Comment: I don't have a problem with either example, is there something about them specifically that you want to avoid? Or is there some problem you are trying to solve that requires the type to be constrained to just three strings? If you made up this problem to learn then I would suggest that you start with a book first as you can wonder all over the place coming up with made up problems. Focus on real world problems, that is what I did and learned a lot.

Comment: Of interest: [Designing with types: Constrained strings](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-more-semantic-types/)

Comment: Of interest: [F# Math (III.) - Defining custom numeric types](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-custom-numeric.aspx/)

Comment: Of interest: [Custom numeric type to limit range F#](http://www.fpish.net/topic/None/74289) This uses the F# Unit of Measure which is a popular suggestion on these problems.

Comment: Of interest: [F7: Refinement Types for F#](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/f7/)

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know what a [refinement type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refinement_(computing)#Refinement_types) is and is that what you are seeking? If so then F# currently does not have them.

Comment: Of interest: [F*](https://www.fstar-lang.org/) F* also has refinement types.

Comment: Why do you need it to be a string?  The discriminated union does exactly what you want it to: constrains the allowed values.  If ever you need to pull a string out of it you can just use the `ToString()` method you defined.

Comment: @GuyCoder Didn't know of refinement types yet. Yes, it is a requirement, I'm trying to represent the object for creating an order in stockfighter: https://starfighter.readme.io/docs/get-orderbook-for-stock.

Comment: @Lawrence I don't exactly need it to be a string, I only need a string representation of it at the end. I was mostly curious if I'm on the right track or if there would be another more feasible approach to it.

Comment: I really don't see that you are far off from a working answer based on what you already have. I would just take a look at [Designing with types: Constrained strings](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-more-semantic-types/) and [F# Math (III.) - Defining custom numeric types](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-custom-numeric.aspx) to get ideas how to polish it.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As people have pointed out in the comments, in general, it sounds like you're asking whether F# has a language feature known as *refinement types*; it doesn't.

In your particular example, however, you can simply define a discriminated union and override its `ToString` method:

```
type Constrained =
    Foo | Bar | Baz
    override this.ToString () =
        match this with
        | Foo -> "Foo"
        | Bar -> "Bar"
        | Baz -> "Baz"
```

This will enable you to convert any `Constrained` value to the string you desire, using the built-in `string` function:

```
> string Foo;;
val it : string = "Foo"
> string Baz;;
val it : string = "Baz"
```

If you find that the above implementation contains too much boilerplate, you can use the `"%A"` format with `sprintf`:

```
type Constrained =
    Foo | Bar | Baz
    override this.ToString () = sprintf "%A" this
```

Since `"%A"` uses reflection, it'll be slower, but the behaviour is the same. There's [a suggestion](https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/7574961-override-tostring-for-discriminated-unions-and-r) to make the language support better in this area.

Comment: By what order of magnitude is it slower? It seems to be more open for change to use `%A`, if I ever wanted to add a possible value to my DU, I don't have to add another case in the `match`.

Comment: @Thaoden Because it might matter to you; I'm giving you the information to the best of my knowledge, but only you have the full picture of what it is that you're attempting to do. Did you read the linked article?

Comment: Thanks for that. - I did. And indeed for my "big picture", it doesn't matter whether the one is faster than the other, as long as we're not talking about 1µs vs 1sec, that's why I asked about the order of magnitude. But I think that path will lead us down deep into off topic...